# vagrant + ubuntu + services + shared folders (nfs) + boot

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, boot, shared-directory

I have a Vagrant box which setups/boots a Ubuntu 12.04 VM (Virtualbox) with a Tomcat app inside of it. The Tomcat app directory (result of a WAR file) really is a NFS shared folder in my project directory (on the host machine).

I'd like to have Tomcat start automatically on VM boot but only after NFS directory is available for to access.

Actually I got different services which should be booted in sequence (postgres -> tomcat -> apache) because on they rely on one another.

How can I achieve that?

I tried putting the following script in `/etc/init.d/start_my_app`:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
service postgresql start
service tomcat7 start
service apache2 start
```

...and `chkconfig -s start_my_app on', but it doesn't seem to work. Services are not runnning.

Can anybody help me?

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597610/vagrant-project-structure-and-vm-services-startup-git).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use a configuration automation tool, such as [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) for provisioning - I found it's declarative language easy to learn, and a lot more readable/maintainable than shell scripts.

Here's my attempt at a puppet manifest to achieve what you described:

```
mount { "/path/to/mountpoint":
    device  => "hostname:/path/to/nfs",
    fstype  => "nfs",
    ensure  => "mounted",
    options => "defaults",
    atboot  => true,
}
->
service { "postgresql":
    ensure => running,
}
->
service {'tomcat':
    name   => "tomcat7",
    ensure => running,
}
->
service {'apache2':
    ensure => running,
}
```

Four resources are described, the nfs mount and the services; the arrows (`->`) between them ensure that they are applied in the same order as they were written in the file (otherwise it is not guaranteed). For the details of the syntax, check the documentation, but I think this is simple enough to be self-explanatory.

(of course it could be a lot more refined, by ensuring that the packages are installed for the services, or that configuration files are set up appropriatly, and so on)

Vagrant has built-in support for puppet provisioning, so you could put the above code in a file called `site.pp`, and place it in a folder next to your Vagrantfile, e.g. `manifests`. Then add to the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
end
```

I only used puppet as an example because that's what I have some experience with - some other examples of such automation tools are: [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/), [Salt](http://www.saltstack.com/), [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home)

Comment: I guess your suggestion involves mounting NFS via puppet rather than via Vagrant to ensure NFS is running before starting the services. Is it correct?

Comment: I believe I understood all your example except for the part relative to mounting the NFS shared folders: do I need to remove `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"` from Vagrant file? how can I refer to `hostname`?

Comment: Well I made a wrong assumption; I thought you already mounted the nfs folders "manually" and not with a Vagrant synced folder, but actually this doesn't make much difference. You can keep both settings - if the nfs is already available when the puppet manifest is applied, it won't do anything about it, and move to the next resource. To get the host name (and to check the mount options), try starting up the VM, and use the `mount` command without parameters - it should show the exact options Vagrant used (including the host ip or name), so you can update the puppet parts based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `init.d` script, you could use an Upstart script that listens for Vagrant's own `vagrant-mounted` event, like so:

```
# /etc/init/my_app.conf

description "Run postgres, apache, and tomcat"

start on vagrant-mounted
stop on runlevel [016]

script
    service postgresql start
    service tomcat7 start
    service apache2 start
end script
```

If, like me, you expected this to be in Vagrant's documentation, you would be quite disappointed.  Its only public acknowledgement is a [bullet point in the changelog for version 0.9.0](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#090-january-17-2012).